# Output to 1 line using cURL

Tags: rest, curl

I am in need to use a cURL command to output 1 word which then will be then used within a variable.

The code that I am using is:

curl --request GET --url $URL --header "Authorization: Api-Token $APITOKEN" --data "name=$KUBENAME" | jq '.[]'

The output I currently get is:
[
{
"id": "KUBERNETES_CLUSTER-33EADA434F5DC0AE",
"name": "dynakube-dev",
"endpointUrl": null
}
]

I would like to filter this output to show only the ID.

"KUBERNETES_CLUSTER-33EADA434F5DC0AE"

Is this possible?

Comment: I've replaced jq '.[]' with:

jq -c '[.values[] | {id: .id}]'

This now shows the ID only:

[{"id":"KUBERNETES_CLUSTER-A100654E803341B1"}]

Is it possible to remove [{"id": ]} from the output?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amended the end with:

| jq -c '[.values[] | .id]'

Answer (score 0):

Try following command,

```
echo '[ { "id": "KUBERNETES_CLUSTER-33EADA434F5DC0AE", "name": "dynakube-dev", "endpointUrl": null } ]' | jq '.[].id'
```

You can rewrite it with command as follows,

```
curl --request GET --url $URL --header "Authorization: Api-Token $APITOKEN" --data "name=$KUBENAME" | jq '.[].id'
```